# Selenium Webdriver using Java - To Check Played Video completed

Tags: java, selenium

I need to automate the Video using Selenium WebDriver (Java). Problem Facing - Script should not be closed until the video gets completed. Video Start time 00:00 and End time (Duration) is -00.33. Upto Video Play script is working fine

Anyone help on further proceeding? how to wait for video to complete and print 'Video played is completed' for more than 50 users individually?

Comment: Could you share your tried attempt first ??